# Finding Mistake After a Conference Proceedings

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission, ieee

Do conferences such as IEEE allow authors to change/update a published conference paper due to some minor issues and mistakes such as equation caption errors or footnote mistakes that do not alter or affect the actual paper's data and information?

If yes, what would be the procedure?

Regards.

Comment: From what I've seen so far, conference proceedings are full of unfixed mistakes and it seems nobody cares about them. If the paper worths reading, it is very likely that you will find its fixed version published in a journal a while later.

Comment: @polfosol This depends heavily on the discipline.

Comment: @JimConant Ironically, I was talking about some highly-disciplined conferences. Anyway, point taken

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you cannot change the *printed version* of a conference paper as soon as it has been printed. Whether or not it is possible to change the *online version* (or to add an errata list) depends on the publisher. Check the publisher's web site and/or contact their author support by e-mail.